# Add-SPOTheme is not recognized – SharePoint Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powershell-cmdlet

I’m a SharePoint Online Administrator, I want to register a customized Company Theme for our Office 365 tenant. Using SharePoint Online Management Shell, I came across the error message “Add-SPOTheme is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program”.

I have tried the solution from this site: https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/add-spotheme-not-recognized with no luck.

I also tried running the command on both 32 and 64 bit versions of PowerShell with no luck.

So, I’m not sure what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` PowerShell module before using the `Add-SPOTheme` cmdlet:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

If already installed, update to latest version.

Follow this documentation: [Get started with SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online)